# SQL how to display time when its not in a key?

Tags: sql, oracle

ERD and code exercise question are below. Issues I am having are:

1. I don't know how to show "if a stock has not been traded show NULL for the date last traded. I tried `nvl(transaction_time, 'NULL')` but I don't think thats right.
2. The exercise asks for the date and time when the stock was last traded, but the foreign key of `"transaction_time"` only shows the date. How would I access the time in SQL code? Do I just do a default time like `SYSDATE?`

I think I have everything else correct that the question is asking for but these two things. I could be wrong though. Thanks in advance

> For each stock listed at each stock exchange, display the exchange name, stock symbol and the date and time when that the stock was last traded. Sort the output by stock exchange name, stock symbol. If a stock has not been traded show NULL for the date last traded.

```
SELECT
    stock_exchange.stock_ex_id,    
    stock_exchange.name stock_exchange_name,
    stock_exchange.symbol,
    trade.transaction_time    
FROM stock_exchange
    JOIN trade
        ON trade.stock_ex_id = stock_exchange.stock_ex_id
ORDER BY stock_exchange.name, stock_exchange.symbol;
```

[ERD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/geOMb.png)

Answer (score 1):

Use an outer join to find stocks which haven't been traded. Oracle DATE datatype includes a time element, you just need to change the date format to display the time element:

```
SELECT stock_exchange.stock_ex_id, 
       stock_exchange.name stock_exchange_name,
       stock_exchange.symbol,
       to_char(max(trade.transaction_time), 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')  as last_traded_time
FROM stock_exchange 
LEFT JOIN trade
     ON trade.stock_ex_id = stock_exchange.stock_ex_id
group by stock_exchange.stock_ex_id, 
       stock_exchange.name,
       stock_exchange.symbol
ORDER BY stock_exchange.name, stock_exchange.symbol;
```

Comment: Thank you! Much appreciated